# What is return type here?

Tags: java, sql

For the query  `"SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM table1"`, what Java type should be mapped to this? `long` or `int` ?

```
int count = rs.getLong(1) ;
```

or

```
int count = rs.getInt(1)  ;
```

Is there any documentation for the COUNT function ?

Comment: Probably depends on what kind of database you're using.  Informix?  DB2?  MySQL?  Oracle?

Comment: It depends. What is your database platform?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html... If you are expecting large values, use Long.

Comment: Depends on how many records you have. Also, Java is not an acronym.

Comment: Can you guys give some documentation link if it is MYSQL SB ? Is anywhere recommended to use LONG values ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are expecting it to be, to be safe use LONG but if it will always be a "small" table you can use int. Btw its a lot easier to try this out yourself or google than that asking here.